# Virtuemart in joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

My virtuemart component code and data of  is in joomla 1.5.

I changed version joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5 but virtuemart component version changed so now not work in joomla 2.5

so How can it possible ?

Comment: You have to download virtuemart dedicated to joomla 2.5 and then migrate data from old website.

Comment: Thanks to reply but how can i migrate data both folder structure are changed

Comment: There is few tutorials about that and there is probably also module that can migrate this data for you.